# How to use event.target inside jQuery child selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if a child-element of a clicked div has a certain class.

So i do this:

```
$('.panel').on('click', function (event) { if($(".panel input").hasClass('h5_validator_error')) { event.stopPropagation(); } });
```

The problem: I have more then one `.panel` class. Since my whole site gets generated by the user and json-files, i need a dynamic environment without **ids**.

So, actually my if-statement is preventing all `.panel`-clicks from doing their job.

I want to do something like this:

```
if($(event.target + ".panel input").hasClass('h5_validator_error')) { event.stopPropagation(); }
```

> So i want to **select all input - elements from the clicked div without
>   having an array and loop through it.**

Is this possible? Or what is the most efficient way of selecting child-elements of the clicked one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use `this` to get the targeted element:

```
$(this).find("input").hasClass('h5_validator_error');
```

or

```
$('input',this).hasClass('h5_validator_error');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoud make the dom object `$(event.target)` and then apply the jquery method on it.

Try this:

```
$('.panel').on('click', function (event) {
    if($(event.target).find('input').hasClass('h5_validator_error')){
      alert('true');
    }
    else{
      alert('false');
    }
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5ksua/2/)